# How to route only certain http/s requests through VPN

Tags: vpn, proxy, openvpn

I'm trying to create a VPN service which is capable of filtering only certain HTTP/S web traffic through the VPN, and other traffic that doesn't match my dynamic filter criteria should be sent through the default gateway.

I know if I use OpenVPN I can route the traffic (Layer 2 & 3) of certain IPs through the VPN and others through the default gateway. But I need to filter traffic similar to how a HTTP Proxy works. I'm actually trying to create my own **Web Proxy Server**, but one that works in a system level rather than on browser level. So even if the users create their own browser client and try to access certain URLs, that traffic can be routed through the VPN. Thus why I thought of creating a VPN which is capable of capturing all traffic originating from the host rather than a simple HTTP Proxy. But now the problem is on how I can filter only the traffic I need to be sent through the VPN by checking HTTP GET/POST requests. Since to do this the VPN needs access to Application Layer data rather than Layer 2 or Layer 3.

So if I summarize my requirement, I'm trying develop my own hybrid between **Web Proxy + VPN (TUN/TAP)** Device.

1. This application/service which the user installs on their machine should be able to intercept all traffic originating from the host.
2. It should be able to check the HTTP/HTTPS requests made from any browser or custom client and only when those requests match certain URL names (i.e. www.facebook.com/* , www.linkedin.com/*, *.js, *.swf), that traffic will be routed through the VPN.
3. If the requests don't meet the matching conditions, they will be sent through the user's default internet gateway.
4. The URL matching conditions can be many and be changed at anytime so they're not hard coded.

Any good hints (code, documentation for OpenVPN plugins I can write, etc) on how I can achieve this, or advice If I'm trying to do this in a wrong way are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Isn't using port numbers good enough?

Comment: I could reroute all packets with destination port as 80 or 443 using routing rules. But still I'm not sure how I could conduct HTTP url maching & filtering.

Comment: If you only want to route a specific server IP `192.168.12.34` via the VPN then `push` a route for it to your vpn clients: eg `push "route 192.168.12.34"`